# Java compiler not optimizing string concatenation

Tags: java, string, compiler-construction, stringbuilder

I have noticed that Java compiler does not converting String addition (+) to StringBuilder.append() method. I have created a class which has only one method

```
public void doSomething(String a, String b) {
    String c = a + "a";
    String d = b + "b";
    String e = c + d;
    String f = e;
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

After compilation and decompilation my method looked like this:

```
public void doSomething(String paramString1, String paramString2)
{
    String str1 = paramString1 + "a";
    String str2 = paramString2 + "b";
    String str3 = str1 + str2;
    String str4 = str3;
    System.out.println(str4);
}
```

Why compiler not optimizing my code? I am using ant for packaging and debug setting is false. I've also tried javac for single java file but result is the same.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe your decompiler smart enough to restore code?

Comment: Can you try: `String g = a + b + c;` and tell us the decompiled result ?

Comment: What decompiler are you using?

Comment: @curiosu: String str5 = paramString1 + paramString2 + str1;

Comment: @RossDrew: I am using JD. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did `javap -c Test.class` and StringBuilder appeared (Java 8).

```
public void doSomething(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
Code:
   0: new           #2  // class StringBuilder
   3: dup           
   4: invokespecial #3  // Method StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   7: aload_1       
   8: invokevirtual #4  // Method StringBuilder.append:(LString;)LStringBuilder;
  11: ldc           #5  // String a
  13: invokevirtual #4  // Method StringBuilder.append:(LString;)LStringBuilder;
  16: invokevirtual #6  // Method StringBuilder.toString:()LString;
  19: astore_3      
  20: new           #2  // class StringBuilder
  23: dup           
  24: invokespecial #3  // Method StringBuilder."<init>":()V
  27: aload_2       
  28: invokevirtual #4  // Method StringBuilder.append:(LString;)LStringBuilder;
  31: ldc           #7  // String b
  33: invokevirtual #4  // Method StringBuilder.append:(LString;)LStringBuilder;
  36: invokevirtual #6  // Method StringBuilder.toString:()LString;
  39: astore        4
  41: new           #2  // class StringBuilder
  44: dup           
  45: invokespecial #3  // Method StringBuilder."<init>":()V
  48: aload_3       
  49: invokevirtual #4  // Method StringBuilder.append:(LString;)LStringBuilder;
  52: aload         4
  54: invokevirtual #4  // Method StringBuilder.append:(LString;)LStringBuilder;
  57: invokevirtual #6  // Method StringBuilder.toString:()LString;
  60: astore        5
  62: aload         5
  64: astore        6
  66: getstatic     #8  // Field System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  69: aload         6
  71: invokevirtual #9  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(LString;)V
  74: return
```

I think the decompiler tries to simplify this to achieve a natural coding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and you are correct. I've added
`String h = new StringBuilder(g).append(a).toString();`
after compilation and decompilation it looked like
`String str6 = str5 + paramString1;`

Comment: @ErcanÖzdemir ah, neat trick. I thought you would have to do javap with your java version.

Answer (score 3):

Your decompiler is indeed simplifying the code.

Consider this source file:

```
public class foo {
    public void a(String[] args) {
        String b = (new StringBuilder()).append("x").append(args[0]).toString();
    }

    public void b(String[] args) {
        String b = "x" + args[0];
    }
}
```

`javap` output:

```
public class foo {
  public foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public void a(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
       7: ldc           #4                  // String x
       9: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      12: aload_1       
      13: iconst_0      
      14: aaload        
      15: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      18: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      21: astore_2      
      22: return        

  public void b(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
       7: ldc           #4                  // String x
       9: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      12: aload_1       
      13: iconst_0      
      14: aaload        
      15: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      18: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      21: astore_2      
      22: return        
}
```

See that the bytecodes are essentially identical: the compiler has transformed method `b` into method `a` using the `StringBuilder.append` optimization.

Now let's see what JD says:

```
public class foo
{
  public void a(String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    String str = "x" + paramArrayOfString[0];
  }

  public void b(String[] paramArrayOfString) {
    String str = "x" + paramArrayOfString[0];
  }
}
```

That's right: JD actually takes the function `a` and interprets it as being a string addition, even though the *original* source code was specified using an explicit `StringBuilder`!

Therefore, we can see that JD will try to reverse the `StringBuilder` optimization if it detects that pattern being used.

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler doesn't do any optimization at compile time because that's left for the JIT at runtime.  If you want to build up a string efficiently across multiple statements, you should use a `StringBuilder`.

The `+` operator compiles into calls on a `StringBuilder` object.  When you write:

```
String c = a + "a";
```

the compiler produces code as if you'd written:

```
String c = new StringBuilder().append(a).append("a").toString();
```

If you use `+` several times within a single expression, such as `a + "a" + b + "b"`, the compiler will use a single `StringBuilder` for the whole expression, calling `append` as many times as necessary.  But it doesn't optimize multiple statements into a single equivalent expression, so if you want to use a single `StringBuilder` to join all your strings together, you'll need to either write it as a single expression or use `StringBuilder` explicitly in your code.

Comment: The StringBuilder optimization is one that is very commonly performed by compilers, not the JIT.

Comment: What, combining multiple statements using `+` into a single larger expression?  I've never seen the compiler do that, and it clearly didn't happen for the OP, nor for Joop Eggen (judging by the bytecode in his answer).

Comment: ? What? Look at Joop's bytecode! The compiler clearly transforms `+` into `StringBuilder.append`. (It doesn't combine multiple adjacent expressions because it isn't allowed to).

Comment: Compiling `+` into `StringBuilder` usage isn't an optimization, that's just how the `+` operator is implemented.  Combining multiple expressions (in order to use a single `StringBuilder` across all of them) is the (potential) optimization that the OP asked about, and Joop's bytecode shows that it doesn't happen.

Comment: The Java standard does not actually mandate using any particular class (StringBuilder included) to implement `+`. Compilers are free to choose any implementation that works, including constant-folding, stringizing (for e.g. `"" + x`), `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.

Comment: In any case, you've misunderstood the question; it wasn't about combining multiple calls together, nor about whether the Java compiler performs optimization (it does). It was a confusion regarding the appearance of `+` in decompiled code.

Comment: It looks to me like the OP was asking why the decompiled code is identical to the original (aside from variable names) instead of being optimized.  Presumably, he expected the compiler to optimize it into something like `System.out.println(a + "a" + b + "b")`.